# Lock stuck open, key is out

Tags: lock, stuck

I was opening a door at my place. You have to turn the key to open the latch while the handle remains locked. I did this and while the key was turned i pushed open the door and the key popped out. Now the lock is stuck open and the key wont go back inside to re-lock the door. Is there any way to fix this without having to replace the lock?

Comment: What kind of lock is this? How old is it? What have you tried so far? Can you provide an image?

Comment: Can you post photos of the lock? (Don't post photos of the key, please)

Comment: Did the weather just turn quite cold?

Comment: Following up from @ThreePhaseEel 's comment, can you do an image search for "key" and post an image of a *similar* key.  (The reason not to post an image of *your* key is that a bad person could use the photo to create a duplicate of the key. See https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/reproducing_key.html - including the comments.)

Comment: A set of lock picks (or improvised picks) could be used to pick the lock back to the unlocked position, but then what guarantee do you have that it won't just happen again?  I feel like any repair would be temporary.

Comment: If its open you could just take it out and take it to a locksmith with the key and have them reset everything. Or maybe a different type of lock. If it's happened once, it's bound to happen again.

Comment: How did you lock it from the inside in the past?  Is it built so a key is required from either side?